# Blender 2d Stroke Tab disappeared in grease pencil panel

Tags: 2d

I am doing 2d work and the Stroke tab in the grease pencil panel disappeared so I can't see my layers anymore. How do I get it back?

[image]
What it used to look like

[image]
What it looks like now